# Truncating a List of Subsets of Ordered Pairs

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a set of pairs:

```
v = {{12300, "h"}, {11600, "cb"}, {9400, "ck"}, {8700, 
   "ds"}, {8600, "ed"}, {12000, "jn"}, {11800, 
   "bb"}, {9000, "co"}, {8800, "di"}, {8300, "ex"}, {8100, 
   "sh"}, {8200, "lo"}, {7200, "ko"}, {2300, 
   "ma"}, {3858, "ps"}, {8500, "ha"}, {8100, 
   "lg"}, {7500, "kc"}, {6300, "xy"}, {3658, "py"}}
```

And I'm sorting all subsets with exactly six elements based on the sum of the elements in the subsets:

```
Sort[List /@ Total[Subsets[v, {6}], {2}]]
```

outputs

```
{{{30816, "kc" + "ck" + "ma" + "md" + "py" + "pu"}}, 
{{31416, "ck" + "lg" + "my" + "ma" + "py" + "pu"}}, 
{{31416, "ck" + "ma" + "md" + "py" + "pu" + "sh"}}, <<38755>>, 
{{65900, "bo" + "cl" + "co" + "dk" + "jo" + "hn"}}, 
{{66100, "bo" + "cl" + "co" + "ck" + "jo" + "hn"}}}
```

I want to be able to truncate that output based on the sums of the numbers so that it will only output the ordered pairs in the 46000-50000 range.

Thanks, j

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Welcome - and thanks for the accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select[Total[Subsets[v, {6}], {2}], First@# >=  46000 && First@# <= 50000 &]
```

Comment: Thank you! Couldn't figure out the that First@# thing! this is great